# Debuggin Expo App in VS Code -No Android project found

Tags: react-native, android-studio, visual-studio-code, expo, vscode-debugger

**Description**:
I'm encountering an issue when attempting to start the debugger for my Expo application in Visual Studio Code. I'm receiving an error message stating: "An error occurred while launching the application. Error while executing command 'h:\projects\projectname\frontend\node_modules.bin\react-native.cmd run-android --no-packager' (error code 101) Android project not found. (error code 1203) (error code 303)".

**Details**:

I'm using Visual Studio Code and have installed the extension: "React Native Tools".

My project is an Expo application, and I am using Android Studio.

I've performed the usual troubleshooting steps, such as checking the project structure, VS Code configuration, and manually starting the Metro bundler, but the problem persists.

I've also updated Expo CLI as a precaution and checked my Node.js version to ensure they are up to date.

My Project Structure is:

-Projectname

->backend

->frontend

->.vscode

Here is my launch.json:

```
   {
      "version": "0.2.0",
      "configurations": [
        {
          "name": "Debug Android",
          "type": "reactnative",
          "request": "launch",
          "platform": "android",
          "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/frontend"
        }
      ]
    }
```

**Question**:
Does anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this issue? Are there specific settings or configurations I need to adjust in VS Code to successfully start the debugger? Or are there alternative methods for debugging my Expo application that I could try?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!